# Delete cell if cell C7 is empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working with Google Apps Script and I am trying to write a simple code (I believe it is going to be simple....)
So what I am trying to achieve is the following:
If cell `C7` is empty, I want cell `A20:A` to clear.

I have tried

> .isBlank()

> "C7" === ""

but none of them seems to work. Can anyone help me solve it? I learned python but apparently Java seems to not function the same way.

Maybe a little help please?

My trial code is this. I think nothing is wrong but why won't it work?

```
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");

    if(sheet.getRange(7, 3).getValue() == ''){
        sheet.getRange("A20:A").removeCheckboxes();
    }
}
```

---

Okay. I decided to share the entire onEdit(e) function I have right now.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    first();
    second();

    function first() {
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        const sName = sheet.getName();

        if (sName === "sheet1") {
            const len = sheet.getRange('B20:B').getValues().filter(row => row[0] != '').length;


            if (e.range.getColumn() === 3 && e.range.getRow() === 7) {
                const range = sheet.getRange(20,1,len,1);
                sheet.getRange('A20:A').removeCheckboxes();
                range.insertCheckboxes().uncheck();
            }


            if (e.range.getRow() > 19 && e.range.getColumn() === 1 && e.range.getValues()[0][0] === true) {
                sheet.getRange('A20:A').uncheck();
                e.range.check();
            }
        }
    }

    function second() {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
        var range = e.source.getActiveRange();

        if(e.range.getRow() == 7 && range.getColumn() == 3) {
            if(sheet.getRange("C7").getValue() == "") {
                Logger.log("C7 is empty");
                sheet.getRange('A20:A').clearContent();    
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

A very dear person from stackoverflow has helped me right the first half of the function. Thank you and shout out to dear friend!!
Second part of the function I very much referenced dear Mateusz. Thank you so much for the help.
However, I still have a problem of not being able to clear the cell whenever cell C7 is empty. Can anyone spot the problem???

Comment: Can you show us how do you use the `.isBlank()` method and how did you try to clear the cell?

Comment: ```function onOpen() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");

    if(sheet.getRange('C7').isBlank()) 
    {
      sheet.getRange('A20:A').removeCheckboxes();
}```


This is what I have done but it doesn't seem to work. As you may have notice, I have a code that makes checkboxes appear in A20:A. I am facing a problem where I manage make them appear but can't make them disappear after clearing cell C7

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");

    if(sheet.getRange(7, 3).getValue() == '')
    {
      Logger.log("C7 is empty");
      sheet.getRange(20,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();      
    }else{
       Logger.log("C7 is not empty");
    }
}
```

code for checking every time C7 cell is edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var range = e.source.getActiveRange();

    if(e.range.getRow() == 7 && range.getColumn() == 3)
    {
      if(sheet.getRange(7, 3).getValue() == '')
      {
        Logger.log("C7 is empty");
        sheet.getRange(20,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();      
      }else{
        Logger.log("C7 is not empty");
      }
    }   
}
```

code to check ecery time a cell is edited:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");

  if(sheet.getRange(7, 3).getValue() == '')
  {
    Logger.log("C7 is empty");
    sheet.getRange(20,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).clearContent();      
  }else{
    Logger.log("C7 is not empty");
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate! But unfortunately, my spreadsheet doesn't seem to activate with that code....

Comment: just switch your if(sheet.getRange('C7').isBlank()) to    if(sheet.getRange(7, 3).getValue() == '') or   if(sheet.getRange('C7'.getValue() == '')

Comment: if you want to start it by opening the sheet then change myFunction() to onOpen()

Comment: I want the code to run whenever C7 is blank so I don't think I should use onOpen(). However, I don't really know how myFunction() works....
I changed my code like the following:

`function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");

  if(sheet.getRange(7, 3).getValue() == ''){
    sheet.getRange("A20:A").removeCheckboxes();
  }
}` 
but it still isn't working....

Comment: I understand. if you want to trigger a function whenever a cell is changed, then use onEdit(e) instead of myFunction()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite

Comment: @user20403203 i changed my answer to onEdit. Just copy & paste. After you added the code you need to Deploy it

Comment: Thank you very much for the help but I still do not see the correct action by the code...
I initially already have an onEdit(e) function written down. Maybe that is the reason why it doesn't work? 
Now I'm beginning to think can there be two onEdit(e) triggers?